# LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found in vs 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I recompiled corba `mico` library with vs2017 and trying to link it to our projects.
(previously everything worked in vs2012)

And have already checked Runtime Library to set to `Multi-threaded DLL(/MD)` all over the place.

Still couldn't solve `one or more multiply defined symbols found` issue and don't understand how `std::exception::what` can be multiply defined.

```
2>strlib.lib(codecvt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>strlib.lib(time.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>strlib.lib(date.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>strlib.lib(timestamp.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>MetaDataAccess.lib(MetadataInterfaceFactory.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>MetaDataAccess.lib(MetadataInterfaceInternal.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>strlib.lib(filepathutilities.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in mico2313.lib(mico2313.dll)
2>   Creating library D:\dev\GIT\SuperSTAR_Mega\superstar2\SuperCROSS\Super32\..\..\..\output\Win32\Release\MetaAccess.lib and object D:\dev\GIT\SuperSTAR_Mega\superstar2\SuperCROSS\Super32\..\..\..\output\Win32\Release\MetaAccess.exp
2>D:\dev\GIT\SuperSTAR_Mega\superstar2\SuperCROSS\Super32\..\..\..\output\Win32\Release\build\MetaAccess.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: Did you upgrade the 2012 vcxproj files or did you start from scratch?

Comment: I compiled 'mico' library in developer command prombt for vs2017 using  'vcvarsall.bat x86' running first for win32. and then in our projects upgraded all platform toolset to v141 and windows SDK version to 10.0.14393.0

Comment: Are you confident that the old build artifacts from mico (dll/lib) are not present somewhere, and picked up when you build your main application? I would maybe try enforcing higher verbosity, or tracing file accesses using something like Procmon to make sure that you are picking up the versions you expect to be in use.

Comment: std::exception does not belong in mico2313.lib.  It was not built correctly, not with /MD.

Comment: I have already checked /MD when compiled mico2313.  One thing I found from mico2313 compile, it generated automatically .def file by using 'dumpbin', so the .def file includes 'std::exception::what'. I think because of this?